# Python: how to move a file with a certain name to a folder with the same name

Tags: python, directory, operating-system

I have a situation in which the directory I'm working at has many files and folders (something like that):

```
AAA_SUBFOLDER
AAA_FILE_1
AAA_FILE_2
BBB_SUBFOLDER
BBB_FILE_1
BBB_FILE_2
```

So files and subfolders both starting with `AAA` or `BBB`(and so on with CCC, DDD..). What I'd like to do is a **python script** that moves all the `AAA` files to the `AAA` subfolder and iterate this for all the files and subfolders with the same names in order to obtain something like this:

```
AAA_SUBFOLDER
  - AAA_FILE_1
  - AAA_FILE_2
BBB_SUBFOLDER
  - BBB_FILE_1
  - BBB_FILE_2
...
```

Can you help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you encounter any issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solution should work for your requirement.
steps:

1. make sure you have python installed
2. save script to a file (lets say main.py)
3. run the saved file with 2 arguments - 1 for path you want to organize, 2 for the delimiter of the subfolder. example: `python main.py -p "D:\path\to\files" -d "_"`

!! this doesn't rearrange inner folders, only top level.

if you got any questions, I'll gladly help.

```
import os
import argparse
from pathlib import Path

def parse_args() -> tuple:
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-p", "--path", default="./files", help="path to the folder that needs organizing")
    ap.add_argument("-d", "--delimiter", default="_", help="delimiter of file names")
    return ap.parse_args()

args = parse_args()

for filename in os.listdir(args.path):
    file_path = os.path.join(args.path, filename)
    if not os.path.isfile(file_path):
        continue
    subfolder_name = Path(filename).stem.split(args.delimiter)[0]
    subfolder_path = os.path.join(args.path,subfolder_name)
    os.makedirs(subfolder_path, exist_ok=True)
    os.rename(file_path, os.path.join(subfolder_path, filename))
```

Comment: Thank you, I had really appreciate your help. It perfectly works!

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution using `pathlib` rename ;) The script as it is assume the current is the path with your files and folders.

```py
# using pathlip
from collections import defaultdict
from pathlib import Path

TARGET_DIR = Path('.') # script dir

FILES_AND_FOLDERS = TARGET_DIR.rglob('*')

# storage with files and folders 
storage = defaultdict(list)
for blob in FILES_AND_FOLDERS:
    if blob.is_file():
        storage['files'].append(blob)
    elif blob.is_dir():
        storage['dir'].append(blob)

# for each dir check if file first 3 characters 
# match if so move by rename
    
for directory in storage['dir']:
    for file in storage['files']:
        if file.name[:3] == directory.name[:3]:
            file.rename(directory / file)
    
# you can look at shutil too
```